# Applying Edge Filter on Video using Canvas in HTML5 but getting lag in video. Is there any better way that i don't get lag?

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

I am using HTML5 Canvas and applying Edge Filter by pixel manipulation. But I am getting lag in the video. Is there any better way to achieve video with edge filter without any lag in video?

Following is the JavaScript I am using with canvas and HTML 5 to apply the effect:-

```
 function sobel (px) {
    px = greyScale(px);
        var vertical = convoluteFloat32(px,
        [-1, -2, -1,
          0, 0, 0,
          1, 2, 1], false);
        var horizontal = convoluteFloat32(px,
        [-1, 0, 1,
         -2, 0, 2,
         -1, 0, 1], false);
        var id = createImageData(vertical.width, vertical.height);
        for (var i = 0; i < id.data.length; i += 4) {
            var v = Math.abs(vertical.data[i]);
            id.data[i] = v;
            var h = Math.abs(horizontal.data[i]);
            id.data[i + 1] = h
            id.data[i + 2] = (v + h) / 4;
            id.data[i + 3] = 255;
        }
        return id;
    }

 function convoluteFloat32 (pixels, weights, opaque) {
    var side = Math.round(Math.sqrt(weights.length));
    var halfSide = Math.floor(side / 2);

    var src = pixels.data;
    var sw = pixels.width;
    var sh = pixels.height;

    var w = sw;
    var h = sh;
    var output = {
        width: w, height: h, data: new Float32Array(w * h * 4)
    };
    var dst = output.data;

    var alphaFac = opaque ? 1 : 0;

    for (var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        for (var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            var sy = y;
            var sx = x;
            var dstOff = (y * w + x) * 4;
            var r = 0, g = 0, b = 0, a = 0;
            for (var cy = 0; cy < side; cy++) {
                for (var cx = 0; cx < side; cx++) {
                    var scy = Math.min(sh - 1, Math.max(0, sy + cy - halfSide));
                    var scx = Math.min(sw - 1, Math.max(0, sx + cx - halfSide));
                    var srcOff = (scy * sw + scx) * 4;
                    var wt = weights[cy * side + cx];
                    r += src[srcOff] * wt;
                    g += src[srcOff + 1] * wt;
                    b += src[srcOff + 2] * wt;
                    a += src[srcOff + 3] * wt;
                }
            }
            dst[dstOff] = r;
            dst[dstOff + 1] = g;
            dst[dstOff + 2] = b;
            dst[dstOff + 3] = a + alphaFac * (255 - a);
        }
    }
    return output;
}

function draw() {
    // First, draw it into the backing canvas
    backcontext.drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.width, video.height);

     // Grab the pixel data from the backing canvas
    var idata = backcontext.getImageData(0, 0, video.width, video.height);

    idata = sobel(idata);
    context.putImageData(idata, 0, 0);

    // Start over!
    setTimeout(draw, 50);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of convolution with a 2D kernel, you can try 1D convolution with the separable convolution approach. This should increase the speed noticeably.

An explanation on how to use separable convolution using Sobel kernels can be found [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2006/10/04/separable-convolution/).

You should change your code to something like this:

```
function convoluteFloat32 (pixels, weights1DHorizontal, weights1DVertical, opaque){
    convolveFloat321DHorizontal(pixels, weights1DHorizontal, opaque);
    convolveFloat321DVertical(pixels, weights1DVertical, opaque);
}
```

And `convolveFloat321DHorizontal/convolveFloat321DVertical` methods are just like the original `convoluteFloat32` method, but they have 3 nested for loops instead of 4.

Comment: Thanks for replying... Actually can you send me the code for the above convoluteFloat32 method in 1D convolution . I am trying to understand the concept of 1D convolution but since i have just begun to work on this i am not getting how to transform the above method to 1D convolution. It would be of great help. Thanks